# ¿Cómo puedo poblar un formulario de HTML con PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

Me explico, estoy creando un formulario que, al ingresar un ID, me muestre la información del solicitante en cada uno de los campos del mismo y que también, cambie los datos.

Mi problema no es el cambio de datos, eso lo manejo, mi problema es que no logro poder mostrar los datos obtenidos desde la base de datos al formulario.

He tratado de hacer un $.post desde jQuery llamando una función de PHP para cargar los datos y nada. También he tratado de llamar directamente la función PHP al formulario pero tampoco me funciona.

Dejo el código abajo.

**CONTROLADOR**
Esta es la conexión a la BD para poder obtener los datos según el ID que se ingrese en el formulario.

```
public function getCuatrimestre($args, $ref){
        if($ref == 1)
        {
            $this->result = $this->execute_query("SELECT * from getCuatrimestre WHERE IdSolicitud =".$args);
        }
        while ($fila = $this->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $elemHTML = "<script>
                            var obj$fila[IdSolicitud] = {    
                                'id_solicitud': '$fila[IdSolicitud]',
                                  'id_persona': '$fila[IdPersona]',
                                     'nombres': '$fila[Nombres]',
                                   'apellido1': '$fila[Primer_Apellido]',
                                   'apellido2': '$fila[Segundo_Apellido]',
                                      'cedula': '$fila[Cédula]',
                                  'id_per_ing': '$fila[IdPeriodoIngreso]',
                                     'periodo': '$fila[Periodo]',
                                        'anio': '$fila[Año]'                                
                            };

                                alert(obj$fila[IdSolicitud]);
                                getCuatrimestreData(obj$fila[IdSolicitud]);

                        </script>";
            print($elemHTML);
        }
    }
```

**JQUERY**
Aquí es donde trato de hacer la carga al formulario

```
function getCuatrimestreData(data)
{
  var nomInput = $("#nomInput");
  var apeInput1 = $("#apeInput1");
  var apeInput2 = $("#apeInput2");
  var cedInput = $("#cedInput");
  var perInput = $("#perInput");
  var anioInput = $("#anioInput");

  nomInput.val(data.nombres);
  apeInput1.val(data.apellido1);
  apeInput2.val(data.apellido2);
  cedInput.val(data.cedula);
  perInput.val(data.periodo);
  anioInput.val(data.anio);
}
```

**INDEX**
Este es el formulario donde pretendo visualizar la información y también donde se va a cambiar los datos.

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">

                    <h4>Información de Cuatrimestre del Estudiante</h4>
                    <hr class="line"/>

                    <div class="form-inline" align="center">

                        <label for=no_sol><b>No. Solicitud:</b></label>
                        <input id=no_sol class="form-control" type="text" style="width:17%;"/>

                        <button id="btnSearchCuatr" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#camcuatr" style="outline: none"><span><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span></button>

                    </div>

                    <div class="card card-body" style="margin-top: 15px;">

                        <div id='cuatrData' class="row" style="width:auto;">

                            <div class="col" style="width:auto;">

                                <label for="nomInput"><b>Nombres:</b></label>
                                <input id="nomInput" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:80%;" disabled/>

                                <br/>

                                <label for="apeInput1"><b>1er. Apellido:</b></label>
                                <input id="apeInput1" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:70%;" disabled/>

                                <br/>

                                <label for="apeInput2"><b>2do. Apellido:</b></label>
                                <input id="apeInput2" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:70%;" disabled/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col" style="width:auto;">

                                <label for="cedInput"><b>Cédula:</b></label>
                                <input id="cedInput" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:55%;" disabled/>

                                <br/>

                                <label for="perInput"><b>Período:</b></label><br/>
                                <input id="perInput" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:auto;" disabled/>

                                <br/>

                                <label for="anioInput"><b>Año:</b></label>
                                <input id="anioInput" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:25%;" disabled/>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr class="line" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom: 30px;"/>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">

                                <div class="alert alert-primary">
                                    <h5>Cambio de Cuatrimestre</h5>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">

                                <label for="perEdit"><b>Período:</b></label><br/>
                                <select id="perEdit" class="custom-select" style="width:50%;"></select>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col">

                                <label for="anioEdit"><b>Año:</b></label>
                                <input id="anioEdit" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:25%;"/>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                               <br/><br/>
                               <button id="saveChanges" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Guardar cambios</button>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Espero por sus respuestas.

Comment: Sabes que puedes hacerlo con ajax y jquery de una manera mas elegante???

Comment: En verdad no uso ajax, por lo que no lo manejo y no he pensado en utilizarlo.

Comment: Como dice Daniel, esto deberías de hacerlo con AJAX ya que no creo que funcione de la forma en que lo haces, pero con AJAX sería mucho más fácil.

Comment: Sino manejas ajax, podrías simplemente recorrer el resultado de la consulta y agregar el resultado en el value de cada input